# Finding files in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

1.) I am trying to search for a file `hello.py`, and return the string in python3 
The file path is `/Users/Joshua/Appdata/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/User_code/Hello.py`
but instead the code returns tons of: `{print("file not here")}`

2.)I can't run `hello.py` atm, cause idk - (1)im not in right directory (2)idk if its module/or script (3)first time in python and im new to it.

3.) how should i have set up python to cause less headache??? should i have installed it to `/Users/Joshua/ >>>>` to cause less headache ?? how did you make it easier for you to learn?

PS: first question im asking on stack overflow...Hooray

```
import os
File = 'hello.py'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/Joshua/Appdata/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/'):  
    if File in files:
        print ("File exists")
    if File not in files:
        print("file not here")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

file_name = "hello.py"
cur_dir = 'C:/Users/Joshua/Appdata/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/'

file_list = os.listdir(cur_dir)
if file_name in file_list:
    print("File Exists")
else:
    print("File not here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Call print only when you have a match

```
import os
File = 'forex.py'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.normpath('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/')):  
    if File in files:
        print (os.path.join(root, File))
    # if File not in files:
        # print("file not here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path

if Path('./Users/Joshua/Appdata/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/').glob('**/hello.py'):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File does not exist')
```